# the difference between to draw up and to write something

Tags: word-choice, word-usage

What is the difference between  between to draw up  and to write in terms of meaning?

I saw it this usage in a sentence like "...draw up a constitution..." and I thought can I say also

" to draw up a company costumer policy " ?

When I google it , google suggests like "how to draw up a contract/ will /business plan/action plan " etc.

But interestingly  most of the results come up  with  " how to write a business plan/company policy" etc.

Can *to  draw up*  suggest more like writing a intricate thing from the scratch ?

and can a robber plan/plot be drawn up?

Comment: 'Drawing up' is a variation of 'draft', which in this instance suggests an initial version that's unlikely to be final (or at least subject to review).  'Writing' a policy is likely to be more permanent.

Comment: *Draw* relates to *draft* (you're *overdrawn* at the bank if you have an *overdraft*), and a *draft* can be defined as a *rough/preliminary sketch*. By implication, when you *draw up* a plan, you *devise/plan* it, whereas if you *write it up* that may simply mean you're the company secretary (and you've got to typeset the plan discussed at the board meeting where you silently sat in taking notes of what was agreed).

Comment: @JHCL Respectfully, you have this backwards.

In professional circles, a first _draft_ is a first go at _formalising_ a document.

_Drafting_ something means creating a text for delivery. Writing is, well, just writing something. In professional circles, _drafting_ is the task of creating a required text to a given standard.

Some are understandably baffled by inexpert usage of the term 'first draft', which actually means 'the first go at creating a full and final text'. A first _draft_ has been _drafted_, not merely written-down by someone.

Anyone can write stuff. _Drafting_ is _discipline_.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Writing* is any example of creating a text.

*Drawing-up* means creating a text intended to serve a clear purpose as well as possible, according to standards understood by a community.

The difference is one of formality and discipline, as is illustrated by the examples that you give:  constitutions, company costumer [do you mean ‘consumer’?] policies, contracts, wills, business plans, action plans.

Each of those is a more or less *formal* document, with certain conventional requirements.  Any of them can be said to have been *written*, in the sense that someone strung the words together.  To say that such a document has been *drawn up*, however, is to stress the fact that it has consciously been *constructed* or *formulated* to some recognised *standard*.

‘Drawing-up’ is related to the term ‘drafting’, [both terms deriving from *draw*, meaning *pull*](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/draft#Etymology), with the implication of *making effort*.  When it comes to texts, *anyone* can simply *write* something.  Drafting, however, is a matter of explicitly aiming for a durable result.  A ‘first draft’ is so called because it is a first step in *drawing-up* something lastingly effective.  It is common to hear that a first draft was sufficiently fit-for-purpose to be adopted without further changes:  even a *first* draft is more formal in intent and *purposeful* than simply ‘writing’ something.  In policy formation, a text that is adopted is identified as *the final draft* or *the accepted draft*.  That does not mean that it is in any sense experimental, sloppy or incomplete—and it might be the first draft, unmodified.

I was once employed for a few years to create speeches and other documents for the CEO of a large institution.  The term in my contract was *drafting*.  *Writing* can be as casual and ephemeral as you like.  *Drafting* or *drawing-up* is always *work*, with formal intentions.

These days I often *write* (or *write-up*) recent progress on some research project or other.  That just means that I am recording it.  When I start preparing it for publication, I consciously shift to *drafting*.

If you propose to spend today *writing* a business plan, then you are saying that you will work on the document, fairly unspecifically.  There is nothing wrong with that.

If you say that you will spend today *drawing up* a business plan, however, you are accentuating the fact that you will, for example, include all of the appropriate sections, in a recognised sequence, and perhaps using a particular corporate style.  By the time you are done *drawing it up*, this document will have reached a certain standard of presentation, and will be fit for a certain purpose.  An informed practitioner will immediately understand the import and interrelations of the document's various components.

This might well also be true of your writing a document, of course, but *drawing up* a plan accentuates this consciousness and satisfaction of formal requirements.  The same goes for the other examples you have given.  Something functionally *amounting to* a will might exist as a set of notes, but *drawing up* a will means conforming to a recognised format and standard.

There might be a comparison with, say, *writing* a story (which could mean the whole thing, or as little as just noting a few possible plot points) or *scripting* a story (which strongly implies the disciplined development of a usable document for performance, in recognisable form).

I am not sure what you mean by ‘a robber plan/plot’.  If you mean the plan for a robbery, [Herman Lamm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Herman_Lamm) really does seem to have elevated the previously haphazard occupation of bank robbery very much to one of *drawing-up* formal plans in an established, tested and effective format.  Where earlier robbers might turn up fairly opportunistically, Lamm essentially created a business process of analysis and formal documentation, at the centre of the robbery-planning process.